# How to host a p2 repository on artifactory oss

Tags: artifactory, p2

I know that artifactory oss version does not support hosting p2 repositories natively.
Is it hovewer possible to do it somehow without such support? I think you cannot get a pro version for free for open source projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have p2 or npm repositories natively you need the Artifactory Pro version.

There are not option to have a free Artifactory pro version without support for opensource projects.

If you don't want to buy Artifactory PRO, there are free alternatives.

Comment: actually I don't understand the fact that they didn't allow p2 hosting in opensource artifactory, as if it was not normal to make opensource eclipse plugins

Comment: Its a market decision.For example, there are a lot of open source projects using NPM and it's not supported in the Artifactory OSS.

Comment: yes, although artifactory oss does support everything related to java dev, like maven/ivy/gradle repositories, so it would be logical to support p2. node.js is not java. :)

Comment: Yes, but it's a market decision. Probably because there are a lot of companies that work with Java using p2 repositories...                           
Also, I know that NPM is not Java but I commented that there are a lot of open source project that are using NPM and Artifactory OSS don't support these types of repos.                                                                                  
You can use another artifact repository manager if you don't want to buy Artifactory PRO,there are free alternatives like[Eclipse Package Drone](https://eclipse.org/package-drone/) :)

Comment: packagedrone does not work, at least version 0.14.1, login page displays error about missing resource, and that's all about it. last commit year ago, or rather, more. so I would say there are no alternatives with enough functionality at the moment. Still, what artifactory does is not hosting but aggregating p2's so if I would make a generic compose p2 repository it would still work, without any need of support from artifactory itself.

Comment: About Jfrog Artifactory It's a market decision, there aren't another reasons.

Comment: I got everything to work - please see if the following steps get you going.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866581/1253097