# How to setting up artifactory for use with node.js artifacts?

Tags: node.js, artifactory

All,

Currently all of our services uses different other internal services and their dependency is resolved by directly giving Bitbucket repository path of the services in the build config file (package.json).

We want to setup a local artificatory where all the internal modules will be made available and dependencies can be resolved from their than from Bitbucket directly.

Can someone give me some pointers how can I do this? What are the various steps involved?

I would set up this for production environment so what factors should I keep in mind while installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to follow this steps:

1. Create your local NPM repo in Artifactory.
2. Replacing the default registry with your new local repository with this command:

   ```
   npm config set registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/your-npm-local-repo-name
   ```
3. Deploy your packages to Artifactory. The first time you can upload the artifacts to artifactory manually or using this command in every project:

   ```
   npm publish --registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/your-npm-local-repo-name
   ```
4. Remove Bitbucket links and replace with only the dependency name and version like:

   ```
   "dependency-name1": "0.0.1",
   "dependency-name2": "0.0.1",
   ```

And publish our projects without Bitbuckets links.

More info here: [Npm Registry with Jfrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-Overview)

Comment: I have an exiting artifactory that is used to store java jars. can i use the same artifactory for node as well? if yes then how?

Comment: @Cloudy Yes, you can use the same Artifactory installation but you need to create a npm repository insside your Artifactory. Got to the Admin panel -> repositories -> local -> New

Comment: what is the best approach : to have a single artifactory or to have multiple artifactory in the same organization ? and this is only thing I have to do. Got to the Admin panel -> repositories -> local -> New   or I have to do something else also.

Comment: @Cloudy The best approach is to have an unique Artifactory installation with multiple repositories (npm repository, maven repository, libs repository, snapshot repository...). Artifactory is designed for this use. Every big company have multiple repositories in the same Artifactory installation.

Comment: So I have already an artifactory that stores java jar files. Now I just need to have the npm repository. Can you provide the detailed step for this.

Comment: @Cloudy You need an admin user in you Artifactory. Go to the Artifactory UI and in the left menu click in Admin -> Repositories -> Local -> New and select NPM as repository type.

Comment: only thats it ? or any configuration changes are also involved. How will I upload the nodejs binaries/artifacts to artifactory.

Comment: @Cloud only these steeps, for upload the  artifacts please read my answer.

Comment: I will do this and will comment here in case I encounter an issue.

Comment: @Cloudy perfect!

Comment: We are using the opensource artifactory, so can I integrate npm/node with artifactory or it is avialable for the enterprize version  only

Comment: @Cloudy sorry but Artifactory OOS don't support npm. Check my response in this post:  [Artifactory OSS compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183338/how-to-host-a-p2-repository-on-artifactory-oss/46215432#46215432)

Comment: What is OOS? And then what would be the solution?

Comment: @Cloudyis the Artifactory Open Source. There aren't solution with Artifactory. You can not use Artifactory opensource for npm repositories.

Comment: Can i use open source nessus to store npm artifact?

Comment: I have a nessus with version 3.0.5 opensource. Is there node repository support for the same.?