# How to have npm dependencies from different registries in the package.json?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, registry, artifactory

In my package.json file I have declared dependencies which one from public registry and second from private registry (Artifactory in this case).

```
"dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.4.4", //public registry
        "ce-ui": "http://myartifactory.com/artifactory/npm-local/ce-ui/-/ce-ui-0.0.2.tgz"
      }
```

I'm looking for way to declare dependencies using caret or tidle e.g.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.4",
    "ce-ui": "^0.0.2"
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you to have a virtual repository in your Artifactory with two repos:

1. Remote repo with the external repo or public registry. Probably you have this URL in your registry.
2. Local NPM repo (your actual local repo).

Then:

- Replacing the default registry with your new local repository with this command:

  ```
  npm config set registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/your-npm-virtual-repo-name
  ```
- Deploy your packages to Artifactory. The first time you can upload the artifacts to artifactory manually or using this command in every project:

  ```
  npm publish --registry http://<ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_DOMAIN>:8081/artifactory/api/npm/your-virtual-repo-name
  ```
- Remove links in your package.json and replace with only the dependency name and version like:

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.4",
    "ce-ui": "^0.0.2"
  }
  ```

More info here:

- [how to setting up artifactory for use with node js artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581503/how-to-setting-up-artifactory-for-use-with-node-js-artifacts/46588177#46588177)
- [Npm Registry with Jfrog Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581503/how-to-setting-up-artifactory-for-use-with-node-js-artifacts/46588177#46588177)

Comment: Great insights!

Comment: @Javier C.
I have 2 module.
One from https://registry.npmjs.org/ and http://abc.pqrs.com.
I want to use both the modules in the same project. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @SantoshHegde In your case you can use the npm scope, for more info: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Answer (score 17):

To have dependencies from different registries referred in same package.json, npm recommends to use scope

Scoped packages will look like

```
"dependencies": {
  "@myorg/mypackage": "^1.3.0"
}
```

You can associate a scope with a registry using npm config:

```
npm config set @myorg:registry http://reg.example.com
```

Once a scope is associated with a registry, any npm install for a package with that scope will request packages from that registry instead of default registry https://registry.npmjs.org

Refer:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope